# Fetching data from remote SQL server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I have developed a asp.net web application using visual studio 2010. I'm using SQL server 2008 as database. I need to fetch data from one of the remote server through LAN connection and have to store to my database through C# code. I am beginner to web development using asp.net and C#. please tell me a very simple way to solve this.

This is an example which I tried. Is this code OK or wrong please guide me with this?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con1 = new SqlConnection();
    con1.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=172.16.7.127\inhouse;User ID=****;Password= *****;";
    con1.Open();
    string str = "select * from t_his_events Where patientMRN="+hosp_no.Text;
    SqlDataReader dr;
    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(str,con1);
    dr = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
    if (dr.HasRows)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("connection established");
    }


}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, a Q&A community for developer support. Please provide details on what you may have tried, including existing code, and outline the specific issues you are experiencing. We will not write the code for you. Please click the edit button to include this information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(<connectionstring>);
SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM table";
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
```

And now you have a DataSet containing the results of your query. As for determining your , I suggest [Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) as a great resource for picking the perfect format.

Comment: will it work if i try to fetch data from another remote system i.e server

Comment: Only if the network has been configured to allow you to access the server remotely. I won't pretend to know enough to talk you through configuring firewalls and the like to enable communication across networks, but if the machine is simply another machine, the above should work.

Comment: yes the machine is simply another machine and with that username and password they have authorized me to fetch the data from the server. it also has SQL server 2008 as database

Answer (score 0):

Where is your database name in connectionString you created on remote server

using System.Data.SqlClient;
using system.Data;

```
string cs = Data Source=172.16.7.127\inhouse;database=databasename;User ID=User id create on remote server;Password= Your password for the ;
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(cs);
SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tableName",conn);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adp.Fill(ds);
```

now you can use the dataset object that contain your table